Understanding the girth of trees
Reading about graph girth, I found out that girth of trees are defined to be infinite. According to the University of Chicago lecture:

Definition 2.6. The girth of a graph is the length of its shortest
cycle. Since a tree has no cycles, we define its girth as inf ∅ = ∞

This definition is counterintuitive for me. If I were to choose I would have chosen zero as the girth of tree graphs.
I'm asking for the logic behind this definition.

This really seems to be a question in set theory - i.e. why should $\inf \varnothing = \infty$? I think of this way: Removing elements from a set should only have the potential to increase its infimum, while adding elements should only increase it.

If $A$ and $B$ are non-empty sets of numbers such that $A\subseteq B$ then $\inf A \ge \inf B$. How do you need to define $\inf \emptyset$ for this property to be true in the case $A=\emptyset$?

@MarkMcClure Your explanation is very intuitive for me. Thanks for the help.
